# How could I extract TMS and WMS link from ArcGIS Server?

Tags: arcgis-server, wms, tile-map-service

I need link of TMS and WMS from our custom ArcGIS maps in order to use in [qlikview](https://www.qlik.com/us/products/qlikview).

How could I extract this link?

Comment: If you're talking about a service, first verify that it has WMTS capabilities and add /WMTS in the url (example: https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer  -->  https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/WorldTimeZones/MapServer/WMTS)

Comment: Thank you @LéoM for the response, I need TMS And WMS , when I add these to the link nothing change  and I saw previous page.

Comment: WMTS - https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/wmts-services.htm  WMS - https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/wms-services.htm